# Is it possible to get variable from Java class to a html file

Tags: java, html, swagger, swagger-ui

I'd like to use the swaggerjson String, to define as a var in a html file.

```
private static BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();


public EtelApplication() {
    printPath();
    beanConfig.setTitle("jim-rest");
    beanConfig.setResourcePackage("com.mast.api");
    beanConfig.setScan(true);
    beanConfig.scanAndRead();
    printSwaggerJson();
    createSwaggerJsonFile();
}


private void printSwaggerJson() {
    String swaggerjson = Json.pretty(beanConfig.getSwagger());
    System.out.println(swaggerjson);
}
```

My html file has this script, where I would like to use the string

```
window.onload = function () {

    const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({name */
        url: "swagger.json", name: "jim-rest",
        dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
        validatorUrl: null,
        deepLinking: true,
        spec: swaggerjson, //this is where I would like to use the var.
        presets: [
            SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
            SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
        ],
        plugins: [
            SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
        ],
        layout: "StandaloneLayout"
    })

    window.ui = ui
}
```

is it possible to use swaggerjson directly like this?

I aplogise for the very simple question, I wasn't able to find a detailed answer when searching

Comment: Easy with Spring Boot.  Have to have a server side component (servlet) of some kind listening for HTTP requests and returning a response.  Can't see it in your question.

Comment: Unfortunately the project doesn't use spring boot, I'm not sure about the servlet. could you descripe what kind of file or method I should be looking for to check for that?

Comment: Please research Java web MVC. You will struggle with a solution if you don’t understand servlets. They are HTTP listeners that run in a container line Tomcat.

Comment: thanks for the hint of what to study. But I've been told the project doesn't use Spring MVC, do you still think it is possible to do?

Comment: You made that clear. Yes it’s possible for someone who understands HTTP, MVC, and servlets. But it’s some work.